# Does Travis CI support PhoneGap application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, travis-ci

I just created an ionic (it is PhoneGap with angularjs) application in Visual Studio 2015. I keeped code on GitHub and want to build it with Travis CI.

According to [documentation](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/getting-started/), it is possible use C# and JAVASCRIPT (WITH NODE.JS). So if I get corect it understands .sln file and could use npm. But I no clue how make it works.

My question is: Is it possible to build PhoneGap app with Travis CI?

Comment: As I see, Travis CI sets up Mono under some Linux OS. Looks like it isn't possible now.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is possible. For example, the mobile app for Travis is using... Travis CI. You can have a look at their [.travis.yml here](https://travis-ci.org/floydpink/Mantis-CI/jobs/10921396/config) to inspire yourself. It uses [Apache ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and grunt to perform diverse tasks.